# multiple cron jobs on one line (running consecutively

Tags: linux, rhel, cron

I researched some examples and came up with two below that seem like they should work but only the first one executes:

```
*/5 * * * * /data/db/test1.py > /data/db/text.txt && hadoop fs -put -f /data/db/text.txt /tmp/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I have also tried

```
*/5 * * * * bash -c '/data/db/test1.py > /data/db/text.txt && hadoop fs -put -f /data/db/text.txt /tmp/' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If I run both commands separately in shell, they work just fine.

Comment: What happens if you switch `&&` with `&` so the second command runs even if the first outputs to stderr.

Comment: && short circuits, so maybe your first command is failing so the second command never runs?

Comment: I have tried with only & and still the same problem. First command executes and overwrites text.txt file, however then second command does not execute

Comment: Instead of `>/dev/null 2>&1`, send the output to a file and see what appears. Maybe hadoop isn't in your search path when run from cron.

Comment: On to something, I get Kerberos error in the mail. I do have a ticket, looking into it

Comment: @MarkPlotnick After investigating error in my mail, I did not have Kerberos ticket. The command line worked after Kerberos was resolved

Comment: @user3508766 Great. If you could,please post an answer to this question, describing what commands, environment variables, etc. needed to be fixed. It will help others who need to use Kerberos and cron together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating error in my mail, I did not have Kerberos ticket. The command line worked after Kerberos was resolved. I wrote a separate script that implemented Kerberos ticket and ran two commands mentioned in this issue. When I run the script from crontab, everything works fine

Comment: Yes, this is the way to solve it. Don't try to do "complicated" things in crontabs, just put everything in a script and schedule that instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda Was a good learning experience